# How does Steam Input measure time?

Tags: steam, steam-input

How are units of time measured in the Steam Input menus? For example, if I set an action's Fire Start Delay to to 100, how long will the delay be?

[image: steam input menu]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are **milliseconds (ms)**. So a Fire Start Delay of 100 ms is a **delay of 0.1 seconds**.

When you see numbers in the context of videogame input and response time, and the numbers range from 10~900, it's almost always milliseconds.

Extra source for confirmation: https://www.reddit.com/r/SteamController/comments/10zlkvh/